# makefile include static library - C

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, static-libraries

I have 2 projects.
The first has 4 files in it:
1. main.c (which include PNM.h)
2. PNM.c (which include PNM.h)
3. PNM.h
4. makefile

```
CC=gcc
LD=gcc
CFLAGS=--std=c99 -Wall -W -Wmissing-prototypes
LDFLAGS=
DOXYGEN=doxygen
RM=rm

AR=ar
RANLIB=ranlib

all: pnm

lib: PNM.o
    @$(AR) ru libpnm.a PNM.o
    @$(RANLIB) libpnm.a

pnm: main.o PNM.o
    @$(LD) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

main.o: main.c PNM.h
    @$(CC) -o $@ -c main.c $(CFLAGS)

PNM.o: PNM.c PNM.h
    @$(CC) -o $@ -c PNM.c $(CFLAGS)

clean:
    @$(RM) -rf *.o

allclean: clean
    @$(RM) -rf pnm
    @$(RM) -rf libpnm.a
```

This project work perfectly.

In my second project, I have 6 files and libpnm.a:
1. libpnm.a
2. main.c (which include matricules.h)
3. matricules.c (which include matricules.h and codebarre.h)
4. matricules.h
5. codebarre.c (hich include codebarre.h and PNM.h)
6. codebarre.h
7. makefile

```
CC=gcc
LD=gcc
CFLAGS=--std=c99 -Wall -W -Wmissing-prototypes
LDFLAGS=
DOXYGEN=doxygen
RM=rm

all: codebarre

codebarre: main.o matricules.o codebarre.o libpnm.a
    @$(LD) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

main.o: main.c matricules.h
    @$(CC) -o $@ -c main.c $(CFLAGS)

matricules.o: matricules.c matricules.h codebarre.h
    @$(CC) -o $@ -c matricules.c $(CFLAGS)

codebarre.o: codebarre.c codebarre.h
    @$(CC) -o $@ -c codebarre.c $(CFLAGS)

clean:
    @$(RM) -rf *.o

allclean: clean
    @$(RM) -rf codebarre
```

(each project is in a separated folder)
when I use

> make

I get an error:
codebarre.c:6:17: fatal error: PNM.h: No such file or directory
 #include "PNM.h"
                 ^
compilation terminated.

same error when I use

> make codebarre.o

I think I don't use my library correctly.  But I don't know how to.

edit: added PNM.h in the directory -> work well

Comment: Can you show us the complete output of `make` and not just the error message?

Comment: You know that double quotes make the preprocessor look into the current directory? Maybe you intend to use angle brackets and add a `-Ipath/to/include/directory` to `CFLAGS`.

Comment: The error message is the only output of make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second project does not have the `PNM.h` file in the current working directory (according to your list). Then the compiler can't find it when compiling `codebarre.c`.

Either you need to copy PNM.h as well, or tell the compiler to look for include files in the directory where `PNM.h` is located using an `-I` option, e.g. with

```
codebarre.o: codebarre.c codebarre.h libpnm.a
    @$(CC) -o $@ -Isomedirectory -c codebarre.c $(CFLAGS)
```

Note that it is **wrong** to name `libpnm.a` as a dependency of the object file. The library should be a dependency of the final executable, e.g.

```
codebarre: main.o matricules.o codebarre.o libpnm.a
    @$(LD) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $^
```

Comment: I put the PNM.h file in my second project's direcory.  It works well.  But is it possible to only put libpnm.a ? I tried  -I./libpnm but it doesn't work.  I looked in libpnm.a and i can only see PNM.o should  I add PNM.h in it ?

Comment: @Adrien No, libraries only contain object files. You should understand that a header declares an *interface* to a library's functions and must be available for the compiler to find at compile time. A compiler or linker will *never* look for headers in libraries, it will only look in the default places and those specified with `-I`.